# Use a specific slide number for slideNumberFormat in xaringan

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan, remarkjs

In a `xaringan` presentation, the `slideNumberFormat` argument is often set to `%current% / %total%`. It is possible to use a specific slide number in this argument?

For instance, if I have a "final" slide like this:

```
---
name: mylastslide
# Thanks
```

with appendix slides behind, I want to display slide numbers like `%current% / %mylastslide%`  with `%mylastslide%` the number of my slide called `mylastslide`.

Thanks.

**[Edit after @user2554330 suggestion]**

For this code, with an incremental slide,

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, PBC"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
---

background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Sharingan_triple.svg)

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

<script>
var slideshow = remark.create({slideNumberFormat : function (current, total) {
  return 'Slide ' + current + ' of ' + (this.getSlideByName("mylastslide").getSlideIndex() + 1); },
  highlightStyle: "github",
  highlightLines: true,
  countIncrementalSlides: false});
</script>

Image credit: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sharingan_triple.svg)

---
class: center, middle

# xaringan

---

hello 

--

world

--

thanks

--

really

--

byebye

---
name: mylastslide

# Final slide

Install the **xaringan** package from [Github](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan):

```{r eval=FALSE, tidy=FALSE}
devtools::install_github("yihui/xaringan")
```

---

# Appendix
````

The last slide (ie appendix) is numbered as `Slide 6 of 9` (and not `Slide 6 of 5`) and 9 is the *url index* of `mylastslide`. (I used `+ 1` in the `slideNumberFormat` function because indexes start at 0.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly set the format to a fixed value for the last slide, e.g. `%current% / 34`.  But you can also set it to a Javascript function.  (Edited to add:) The tricky part is that you need to include all the options that would normally appear in the `nature` argument as well.  So  you want something like

```
<script>
var slideshow = remark.create({slideNumberFormat : function (current, total) {
  return 'Slide ' + current + ' of ' + this.getSlideByName("mylastslide").getSlideIndex(); },
  highlightStyle: "github",
  highlightLines: true,
  countIncrementalSlides: false});
</script>
```

You name a slide by putting the text

```
name: mylastslide
```

at the bottom of the slide after `---` marks.  So here's a complete example, based on the first few slides of the `xaringan` template:

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, PBC"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
---

background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Sharingan_triple.svg)

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

<script>
var slideshow = remark.create({slideNumberFormat : function (current, total) {
  return 'Slide ' + current + ' of ' + this.getSlideByName("mylastslide").getSlideIndex(); },
  highlightStyle: "github",
  highlightLines: true,
  countIncrementalSlides: false});
</script>

???

Image credit: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sharingan_triple.svg)

---
class: center, middle

# xaringan

### /ʃaː.'riŋ.ɡan/

---
class: inverse, center, middle

# Get Started

---
name: mylastslide

# Hello World

Install the **xaringan** package from [Github](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan):

```{r eval=FALSE, tidy=FALSE}
devtools::install_github("yihui/xaringan")
```
````

This has 5 slides, numbered "1 of 4" to "5 of 4".

Edited to add:  As discussed in the comments, this doesn't handle incremental slides properly:  `getSlideIndex()` counts incremental slides separately.  We want to use `getSlideNumber()`, which stays the same on all of them when we use the option `countIncrementalSlides: false`.  However, the online version of `remark-latest.min.js` doesn't have `getSlideNumber()` in it, you need to ask for `remark-0.15.0.min.js`.

You do this with the following YAML:

```
      xaringan::moon_reader:
        lib_dir: libs
        chakra: https://remarkjs.com/downloads/remark-0.15.0.min.js
```

After this the code below worked fine:

```
<script>
var slideshow = remark.create({slideNumberFormat : function (current, total) {
  return 'Slide ' + current + ' of ' + this.getSlideByName("mylastslide").getSlideNumber(); },
  highlightStyle: "github",
  highlightLines: true,
  countIncrementalSlides: false});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the output I wanted. However, it does not take into account incremental slides (with `--`) [maybe it's another function than `getSlideIndex`], and other argument in `nature:` are not taken into account (like `ratio` or `scroll`) [I tried to specify the js script like `slideNumberFormat: "slidenumber.js"` in the yaml but it does not work]

Comment: The first issue is a consequence of the second with the `countIncrementalSlides` argument I think.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  I can't spot a way to update the slide options, so you'll need to put anything that would have appeared in "nature" into the `remark.create` call.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, this works. But (I'm sorry), `getSlideIndex` gives the index of the slide (used in the url) but not the expected displayed number (which can be different with incremental slides). I tried `.getSlideNumber()` at the end but this make the presentation to block at the first slide...

Comment: I really appreciate your help, sorry for not demonstrating it... I updated my question with an example. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Defining a custom custom JS function allows me to number differently main slides ("current/final") and annexes ("current"), and that's already really cool. Too bad for hard coding!

Comment: I've added a simpler fix now.